# EPPlus C# Export data to Excel. Table data overwrites Namebox instead of "Insert" and preserving other cells

Tags: c#, excel, insert, epplus, overwrite

I am using EPPlus C# library to generate Excel file. An Excel template is to be filled with SQL Server data that is coming in a DataTable. Template file uses NameBoxes, the data is filled within those nameboxes.
The issue is that for eg. I have namebox at position A1
[image]

and another namebox at position B1

[image]

when A1 is filled with a single row data.. it is fine. But if data in A1 has multple rows it overwrites A2 namebox (namebox at A2 is gone).

[image]

The namebox at A2 should be shifted down to A6.

[image]

(Same behaviour we see when doing "Insert" in a cell that shifts other cells ahead instead of overwriting them).

Comment: Can you post a MCVE?

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by inserting new rows using the following logic:

```
   // Get current cell's address
                            string oldAddress = nameBox.Start.Address;
                            // insert new rows in worksheet to preserve other nameboxes
                            nameBox.Worksheet.InsertRow(nameBox.Start.Row, dt.Rows.Count);
                            // move to old address
                            nameBox.Address = oldAddress;

                            // Fill Name box with Datatable
                            nameBox.LoadFromDataTable(dt, printHeaders);
```

Answer (score 1):

And what about the Insert method from Rows collection?

```
// Insert row at the 4the position.
worksheet.Rows.Insert(3);
```

Comment: EPPlus function ExcelNameRange.LoadFromDataTable(datatable) is used to populate namebox.